# C# Expose strongly typed dictionary keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am sure I am not going to use the correct words to explain but I hope you understand what I am trying to accomplish.
   I have a class that gets passed in dictionary collection. Is it mandatory that this passed in dictionary collection has certain keys that this class needs. I would like to be able to expose publicly those keys needed by the class, but not just as strings, but actual items. An enumeration would work but since this class is a base class I dont think that is a good solution. I need something similar to the Resources class that is generated everytime you add items to the Resources.resx file. So you that you can just go to Resources.Resources.MyLabel1, Resources.Resources.MyLabel2, etc.
   Is this possible?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Are all of the keys of the same type, or at least a common ancestor?

Comment: Given that you mention an enum, there's a class I did on Codeplex a while back called SpecializedEnum that sounds like it might fit your needs. http://specializedenum.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just offer a static or const member on your class:

```
class PickyClass {
  public static readonly string[] RequiredKeys = new[] {"length", "width"};

  /// <summary>
  /// Please note that you must include at least RequiredKeys in values
  /// </summary>
  public void Setup(Dictionary<string,string> values)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

(edit) or is it important that they are addressable by name? In which case, how about:

```
class PickyClass {
  public class RequiredKeys
  {
    public const string Length = "length";
    public const string Width = "width";
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Please note that you must include every const in RequiredKeys in values
  /// </summary>
  public void Setup(Dictionary<string,string> values)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you second option is the one I am going to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create properties that expose your values

```
public class MyClass

    private Dictionary<string,string> _dict;

    public MyClass (Dictionary<string,string> dict)
    {
        _dict = dict;
    }

    public string FirstName { get { return _dict["FirstName"]; } }
    public string LastName { get { return _dict["LastName"]; } }
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you can aslo create read/write properties

```
public string FirstName { 
    get { return _dict["FirstName"]; }
    set { _dict["FirstName"] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a detail you should hide

```
public void Setup(Dictionary<string,string> values)
```

If `values` must contain certain keys, then maybe you could encode that information in your own dictionary type.

```
public class FussyDictionary : Dictionary<string,string> {
  // You must provide these values
  public FussyDictionary(string valueA, string valueB) {
     Add("magicKey1", valueA);
     Add("magicKey2", valueB);
  }

  // Override remove to stop you removing these keys?
}
```